# Knowing if washing machine is new or used?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

So where I live, at places like Home Depot and Best Buy, washing machines start at $650 + tax + transportation as I live in a walk-up.

In sites like craigslist and marketplace I've seen users sell new washing machines at lower prices, with transportation included.

Is there a way to know that these "new" washing machines are really *new*?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean unused: probably not, without fully disassembling them to check for wear. There may be ways to check serial number for manufacturing year, if you can get the serial number.

You can always ask the seller why they're selling it (then decide if you believe their story). If it's because they're moving away and not taking it with them, this may be a good deal even if it is only "newish". Otherwise, it may or may not be damaged, stolen, or anything else.

You almost certainly won't have a valid warranty, unless that manufacturer's warranties are explicitly transferable.

Caveat emptor. If it sounds too good to be true, it's probably too good to be true.

Note that you may be able to find functioning "definitely not new, but free and worked last time I used it" machines on share and recycle sites. Your town may have such a service, or someone may have set up a list for your area on Freecycle or something like it.

Comment: I would google people/companies selling new stuff on those sites.  Paying with credit card will add a little bit of safety in case of scams.

Comment: Could be scratch/dent appliances as well

Comment: True, though stores often sell those directly if you ask about them.

Comment: Old isn't always bad; my sister still uses the maytag set my parents got for a first-house present in the 60s, while a friend of mine has bought 2 new ones in the past 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the seller is a wholesale or retail company, (they sometimes advertise in those sites), you will not be purchasing an item that is new, (As defined as you being the original first purchaser end user.)

Often "New" is used to describe the *condition* of an item.  However "new" can mean different things to different people. This can range from, just very recently purchased and not used, to purchased sometime in the last 5 years...or beyond.

Unfortunately there is nothing to prevent someone from describing an item that is not fully true about it's condition or length of ownership.

It is your responsibility to determine if what you are buying is equal or greater than the consideration that you are exchanging for it.

This is definitely a case of "Buyer beware."